# When i change the dutycycle on my PWM it doesnt move my servo

Tags: pwm, servo

I am using an SG90 and the GPIO Pin #17 but it only sometimes turns when I run the code. It always works if I reset the Kernel everytime.

I am connected to my Pi through putty and am running the code in Jupyter Notebook.

Connections:
[image: Connections on Raspberry Pi]

The code:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(17,50)

p.start(0)
time.sleep(3)

p.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
time.sleep(2)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(12)
time.sleep(2)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(7)
time.sleep(2)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
time.sleep(2)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)


p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: BCM GPIO 17 is connected to physical pin 11.  Is that what you are using.  Can you add a photo of the connections?

Comment: yes it is connected to the 11th pin. thank you for editing the post

Comment: Connections look okay.  Does the following work?  `sudo pigpiod` followed by `pigs s 17 1500 mils 2000 s 17 1000 mils 2000 s 17 2000`

Comment: I just figured out that my code does work but I have to reset the Kernel everytime i have run it for it to work again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reset the Kernel".  It should work again without doing anything like that.

Comment: **Are you powering a servo off of your GPIO?** I wouldn't do that. Those GPIO pins are not intended to be power sources but rather signals you use to turn things (like relays) on and off. That way you won't damage the RPi circuitry hooked up to those GPIO pins, because devices get power from a separate source... [Power supply circuit for powering SG90 servo. How to handle high current requirements?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246642/power-supply-circuit-for-powering-sg90-servo-how-to-handle-high-current-require#246645)

Comment: If you look at the photo you will see that the servo is being powered from the 5V and ground pins.

Comment: Ditto joan WRT "reset the Kernel" -- it would be better if you just said what you did in literal terms, because that phrase is meaningless in context (ie., it's nonsensical) or at best extremely ambiguous.